# Mutate if col name contains 'dat' to date

Tags: r, data-manipulation, dplyr

I have the following df where num, chr, num

```
       dat a     idat
1 20200101 h 20200101
2 20200113 g 20200113
3 20200213 b 20200213
```

I would like to get date, chr, date

```
       dat a     idat
1 2020-01-01 h 2020-01-01
2 2020-01-13 g 2020-01-13
3 2020-02-13 b 2020-02-13
```

I tried a lot of things including:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(vars(contains("dat")), function(x) 
    {as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d")})
```

Does someone have a suggestion? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `mutate_if`, we need `mutate_at`.  In the newer version of `dplyr`, it can be done with `mutate` and `across`

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.0.0
df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(across(contains('dat'), ~ as.Date(as.character(.), format = '%Y%m%d')))
```

---

Prior to `1.0.0`, `mutate_at` can be used

```
df1 <- df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(contains('dat')), ~as.Date(as.character(.), format = '%Y%m%d'))
```

`mutate_if` is generally used to check some condition based on the values of the columns, i.e.

```
df  %>%
      mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ as.Date(as.character(.), format = '%Y%m%d'))
```

As a reproducible example

```
head(iris) %>%
         mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ .x * 5)
```

Comment: thank you! But the first two give an error, is this because the columns ```dat``` and ```idat``` are numeric? And therefore ```format = '%Y%m%d'``` does not work because its not a chr?

Comment: @Maya thanks, I corrected.  It needs to be converted to `character`

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` approach that uses the same logic as akun's `tidyverse` answer

```
library( data.table )
DT <- fread("dat a     idat
 20200101 h 20200101
 20200113 g 20200113
 20200213 b 20200213")

cols <- grep( "dat", names(DT), value = TRUE )
DT[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, function(x) as.Date( as.character(x), format = "%Y%m%d" ) ), .SDcols = cols ][]
```